# Is there a way to make a 5 star rating system using django restframework with the models I have created?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, rating-system

I am trying to make an API using django RESTframework for a 5-star rating system. **The API should render the list of all products in the home URL, and on each product, the average rating must be displayed. On clicking that, all the reviews for that particular product must be enlisted.**

I have made my models, and views and the serializers.py file. The directory level is shown:

```
project_rating
├── reviews
│   ./apps.py
│   ./tests.py
│   ./views.py
│   ./admin.py
│   ./models.py
│   ./migrations
├── manage.py
├── api
│   ./apps.py
│   ./tests.py
│   ./urls.py
│   ./views.py
│   ./admin.py
│   ./models.py
│   ./migrations
│   ./serializers.py
```

My reviews/models.py looks like this:

```
class product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    review = models.ForeignKey('feedback', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default = "NA")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class feedback(models.Model):
    SCORE_CHOICES = zip(range(6), range(6) )    
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50, null= True, default='anonymous user')
    item = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null= True)
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=SCORE_CHOICES, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Rating(Item ='+ str(self.item)+', Stars ='+ str(self.rating)+')'
```

The api/serializers.py looks likes this:

```
class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.feedback
        fields=(
            'id',
            'user',
            'rating',
        )

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.product
        fields=(
            'id',
            'title',
            'description',
            'review',
        )
```

My api/views.py is:

```
class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset= models.product.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers.ProductSerializer

class ReviewList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset=models.feedback.objects.all()
    serializer_class= serializers.RatingSerializer
```

The api/urls.py is :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.ProductList.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.ReviewList.as_view()),
]
```

The problem I am facing:

***Q.I need to add a URL in the product_list(homepage) to link all the feedbacks for that product. How to add such URL and and make that URL display only those feedbacks which were made for that particular product?***

I have tried to look for many available answers online, but couldn't solve my problem. If this question is redundant, kindly refer to the links which precisely solve my situation.

**The github link to full code is :** https://github.com/rjsu26/5-star-rating

Comment: What you are asking for is completely doable and quite straight forward, but you may need to read up on the documentation of Django Rest Framework. At the same time, you will have a better chance at getting a positive response and help if you ask a specific question about a specific problem – and not 3 open questions. See  [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Okay, I will read the docs. And I am removing the last 2 questions. If u can facilitate me with some hint, then kindly do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write you own `list` method in `ProductList`.

Check [github](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L39) on how it looks in default. Then create such method in your class and add your logic there